# Collapsing tool bar layout collapse automatically

Tags: android, android-design-library

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#0000ffff"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dip"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/topImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/topView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bl" />


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="top"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:title="">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/quila_name2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageVdiewiew"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/walterwhite"
    app:border_color="@android:color/white"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_behavior="saulmm.myapplication.AvatarImageBehavior" 
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

On Expanding and collapsing My Collapsing Toolbar Layout Is show an Spring  effect.On expanding up to half it automatically collapsed.The collapsing tool bar is stacking on expanding and collapsing i tried form my side please give some help to solve this issue.My collapsing toolbar automatically collapse when i try to expand it Collapsing layout collapse automatically if remove the touch on certain point

Comment: Please add more clarity and improve your title.

Comment: if i leave the scroll on certain point my collapsing  automatically collapse also when I try to expand it .collpse automatically

Comment: Please check my answer and tell us why are you using that `ViewPager` it's for tablayout or?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from `ViewPager` and you are using it in [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html).

> `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is a wrapper for **Toolbar** *which implements a
>   collapsing app bar*. It is designed to be used as a direct child of a
>   AppBarLayout.

Maybe you wanna try that in `NestedScrollView` (also, *for your contents too*)and, as i see, you have `RecyclerView` too.(`RecyclerView`'s position looks good).but, that causes an error with `ViewPager`.(you could be clear about using that `ViewPager` and tell us why are you using that, e.g for `TabLayout` or etc)

And, put that Toolbar inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.